# Issuse: Scipy Fitting Normal Data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, data-fitting

I currently have some experiemental data imported and plotted which is normally distributed.

[image: Normally Distributed Experiemental Data]

I then tried using Scipy to fit a normal distrubtion to the data:

```
from scipy.stats import norm

def normal_fit(data, offset):
    x = numpy.linspace(0, len(data), len(data))
    params = norm.fit(data - offset)
    normal = norm.pdf(x, params[0], params[1])

    return normal, params
```

However it calculates a mean and standard deviation *(4504, 2961)* that is incorrect - plotted in red below.

How can I fit the data properly?

**Edit:** Data is offset to zero as suggested by [ev-br](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143765/ev-br), this produces parameters that still don't make much sense *(954, 2961)*

Comment: FYI numpy.linspace(0, len(data), len(data)) is just np.arange(len(data)), which is shorter

Comment: Can you include the code you use to plot the data? Is it obtained from a histogram ? If it's your raw data it's not gaussian, it's just a bell curve

Comment: What is the blue curve?  If you are trying to fit a [Gaussian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function) to data whose graph looks like a "bell curve", `norm.fit()` is the wrong method to use.  For that type of fitting, use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()`.

Comment: The data is just a bell curve. I try the suggested way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played with similar problem [Curve fiting of normal distribution in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42882309/curve-fiting-of-normal-distribution-in-python/42884014#42884014)

added `b`, a offset to the curve fit, seems to need a halfway OK guess value

then the scale factor sign changed?? to I just patched over it, don't understand myself

here is the reworked code with curve_fit, also finds offset:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([ 0.47712125,  0.5445641 ,  0.61193563,  0.67924615,  0.74671202,
    0.81404772,  0.88144172,  0.94885291,  1.01623919,  1.08361011,
    1.15100191,  1.21837793,  1.28578227,  1.3531658 ,  1.42054981,
    1.48794397,  1.55532424,  1.62272161,  1.69010744,  1.75749472,
    1.82488047,  1.89226717,  1.9596566 ,  2.02704774,  2.09443269,
    2.16182302,  2.2292107 ,  2.29659719,  2.36398595,  2.43137342,
    2.49876254,  2.56614983,  2.63353814,  2.700926  ,  2.76831392,
    2.83570198,  2.90308999,  2.97008999,  3.03708997,  3.10408999,
    3.17108999,  3.23808998,  3.30508998,  3.37208999,  3.43908999,
    3.50608998,  3.57308998,  3.64008999,  3.70708999,  3.77408999,
    3.84108999,  3.90808999])/2
y = np.array([  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
     0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
     0.00000000e+00,   5.50000000e+01,   1.33500000e+02,
     2.49000000e+02,   4.40000000e+02,   7.27000000e+02,
     1.09000000e+03,   1.53000000e+03,   2.21500000e+03,
     3.13500000e+03,   4.44000000e+03,   5.57000000e+03,
     6.77000000e+03,   8.04500000e+03,   9.15500000e+03,
     1.00000000e+04,   1.06000000e+04,   1.06500000e+04,
     1.02000000e+04,   9.29000000e+03,   8.01500000e+03,
     6.50000000e+03,   5.24000000e+03,   4.11000000e+03,
     2.97000000e+03,   1.86000000e+03,   1.02000000e+03,
     5.26500000e+02,   2.49000000e+02,   1.11000000e+02,
     5.27000000e+01,   6.90825000e+00,   4.54329000e+00,
     3.63846500e+00,   3.58135000e+00,   2.37404000e+00,
     1.81840000e+00,   1.20159500e+00,   6.02470000e-01,
     3.43295000e-01,   1.62295000e-01,   7.99350000e-02,
     3.60750000e-02,   1.50000000e-02,   3.61500000e-03,
     8.00000000e-05])+10000
#numpy.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=2.0, size=100)
'''
norm.pdf(x) = exp(-x**2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)
norm.pdf(x, loc, scale) == norm.pdf(y) / scale with y = (x - loc) / scale
'''
def datafit(x,N,u,sig,b):
    y = N*np.exp(-((x-u)/sig)**2/2)/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)) + b
    return y
popt,popc = curve_fit(datafit,x,y,p0=[np.max(y),2,2,1000])

# scipy norm.pdf with scaling factors to match datafit()
scale = abs(popt[2]) # I don't know why, but it 1s needed with b
Normal_distribution = popt[0]*scale*norm.pdf(x, popt[1], scale) + popt[3]


plt.plot(x,y, 'b-')
plt.plot(x, datafit(x+.1, *popt), 'g')
plt.plot(x, Normal_distribution, 'r')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to subtract the zero level first.

Comment: I realised this myself - this still returns the parameters (954, 2961)